# Função de mask CNPJ para campo com valor dinâmico

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou com uma dúvida na seguinte ocasião, tenho um função de maskCNPJ onde a função obviamente adiciona uma máscara no número do CNPJ do fornecedor. O problema que está acontecendo, vem do fato que a função só funciona no primeiro CNPJ que vem ao carregar a página, já que, quando eu seleciono outro fornecedor, é trago o seu CNPJ e seu ID, logo, o campo de CNPJ não fica com a máscara. Alguem sabe me dizer como faço para que a máscara acompanhe o número do CNPJ, mesmo ao mudar o fornecedor ?

index.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$servidor = 'localhost';
$usuario = 'root';
$senha = '';
$dbname = 'testevip';

$connect = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname);

# Fornecedores
$query_fornecedores = "SELECT nome FROM fornecedores ORDER BY nome ASC LIMIT 20";
$result1 = mysqli_fetch_all(mysqli_query($connect, $query_fornecedores), MYSQLI_ASSOC);

# Produtos
$query_produtos = "SELECT * FROM produto ORDER BY desc_produto ASC";
$result2 = mysqli_fetch_all(mysqli_query($connect, $query_produtos), MYSQLI_ASSOC);

mysqli_close($connect);
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <!-- Essas duas linhas são do Bootstrap, deixa a formatação mais 'bonita' -->
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Testando API</title>
</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mask.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>


<body onload="dataAtual()">

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container" id="cabecalho">
        <br>
        <header class="cabecalho">
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="imagem-header">
                    <img src="imagens/logo_ip.png" alt="Logo Varejão Irmaãos Patrocinio">
                    <h1>Vales - Varejão Irmãos Patrocinio</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="dados-header">
                    <div id="id-pedido"></div>
                    <div id="data-atual"></div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </header>
    </div>

    <div class="container" id="fornecedores">

        <div class="title-padrao">
            <h1 class="text-center">Fornecedores</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="fornecedores-wrap">
            <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 select_height text-center">
                <b>ID:</b>
                <div id="fornecedor-id" class="font-pop"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-8 select_height" id="div_fornecedores">
                <!-- selectpicker é o elemento que coloca o input e o select juntos -->

                <b>Fornecedor:</b>
                <select class="selectpicker form-control" data-show-subtext="false" data-live-search="true"
                        name="select_fornecedor<?=$id?>" id="select_fornecedor<?=$id?>" onchange="initFornecedores(<?=$id?>)">
                    <?php
                    foreach ($result1 as $item_fornecedores) {
                        echo '<option data-subtext="' . $item_fornecedores['nome'] . '" value="'
                            . $item_fornecedores['nome'] . '">' . $item_fornecedores['nome'] . '</option>';
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-3 text-center select_height">
                <b>CNPJ:</b>
                <div name="cnpj" class="font-pop" id="cnpj"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</body>
<script>
    dataAtual();
    initFornecedores();
    initProdutos();
    initPedido();
</script>
</html>
```

Funções do JQuery / AJAX:

```
function mask() {
    $('#cnpj').mask('99.999.999/9999-99');
}

function initFornecedores(){
    var letras_fornecedores = document.getElementById("select_fornecedor").value;
    var $cnpj = $('#cnpj');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "API.php",
        data: {
            "mode": "fornecedores",
            "letras_fornecedores": letras_fornecedores,
        },
        dataType:"JSON",
        //CASO DÊ TUDO CERTO
        success:function(data){         
            console.log(data);
            document.getElementById('fornecedor-id').innerHTML = data[0]['id_fornecedor'];
            $($cnpj).text(data[0]['cpf_or_cnpj']);
            mask();
        },
        error:function(request, error)
        {
            // console.log("Request: " + JSON.stringify(request));
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o método `.unmask()` antes de aplicar a máscara novamente:

```
$cnpj.unmask().text(data[0]['cpf_or_cnpj']);
```

> Note que troquei `$($cnpj)` por apenas `$cnpj` porque a variável
>   `$cnpj` já é o elemento em objeto jQuery. Portanto não é necessário
>   colocar dentro de `$()`.

**[Documentação do Plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html)**

Comment: Muito obrigado Sam, fiz o teste e funcionou perfeitamente !